# is there a way in lua to find a value in a table without looping?

Tags: loops, lua, nested-loops, postgresql-9.2

I have the following table which represents data for a single widget:

```
 id  , c_id, grp,   grp_name ,       label      , seq, type , field, field_type , value    
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , type1 , dgmp  , text  , 0
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , extension   , text  , 1111
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , type1 , meec   , text  , CC5C9788
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , password  , text  , test
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , fwnoansenable , boolean , false
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , fwenable , boolean , false
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , fwsenable  , boolean , false
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , slenable  , boolean ,
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg2 , fwnoans , text  ,
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , type1 , adminpassword , text  , afd((@&))
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , type1 , template  , select  , 
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , type1 , snserver  , text  , 127.0.01
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg2 , fwallenable  , boolean , false
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg2 , password  , text  ,
 246 , 17 , type1 , type1 grp1 , 5 - Widget XXX , 7 , reg1 , cerid  , text  ,
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , chistoryenable , boolean , true
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , sdenable , boolean , true
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , mailcback  , text  ,
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , mb   , text  ,
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , dndenable   , boolean , true
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , cwtenable , boolean , true
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , fwing  , boolean , true
 246 , 11 , type2 , type2 grp3 , 1 - Widget YYY , 1 , type2 , hleenable , boolean , false
 246 , 15 , type3 , type3 grpA , 3 - Widget MMM , 3 , type3  , free  , boolean , false
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to look up multiple field values without having to loop through each detail record, because it's possible I'll have up to 10,000 widgets, each with this amount of detail.

I will need to extract the values for the 'field':

```
  field           value I'm expecting
  meec             CC5C9788
  extension        1111
  hleenable    true
```

I would also somehow need to extract all the unique c_id's and the label.  SO for example,
I would need the following data extracted:

```
 17, '5 - Widget XXX'
 11, '1 - Widget YYY'
 15, '3 - Widget MMM'
```

If I have to loop through each record I will, but I wanted to know if there's another more efficient way that I am not thinking of.

For example, back in the day when I used to work with ADO, I could run select statements against a csv file, eventhough it wasn't a database. 
Similarly, I'm  wondering if I can treat the lua table in memory like a table in a db and run select statements against it. 
If not, any other suggestions?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

here's what the table actually looks like in lua, in case it helps. 
As you can see, it returns an index number, which is auto generated for me.

```
  widget["label"] = "widgetdetail"
widget["type"] = "grp"
widget = {}
widget[10] = {}
widget[10]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[10]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[10]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[10]["grp"] = "grp2"
widget[10]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[10]["name"] = "fnoa_enable"
widget[10]["seq"] = "7"
widget[10]["type"] = "boolean"
widget[10] = "false"
widget[11] = {}
widget[11]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[11]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[11]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[11]["grp"] = "grp2"
widget[11]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[11]["name"] = "extension"
widget[11]["seq"] = "7"
widget[11]["type"] = "text"
widget[11] = ""
widget[12] = {}
widget[12]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[12]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[12]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[12]["grp"] = "grp1"
widget[12]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[12]["name"] = "fnoa"
widget[12]["seq"] = "7"
widget[12]["type"] = "text"
widget[12] = ""
widget[13] = {}
widget[13]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[13]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[13]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[13]["grp"] = "grp2"
widget[13]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[13]["name"] = "sl_enable"
widget[13]["seq"] = "7"
widget[13]["type"] = "boolean"
widget[13] = ""
widget[14] = {}
widget[14]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[14]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[14]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[14]["grp"] = "grp1"
widget[14]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[14]["name"] = "f_busy"
widget[14]["seq"] = "7"
widget[14]["type"] = "text"
widget[14] = ""
widget[15] = {}
widget[15]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[15]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[15]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[15]["grp"] = "grp2"
widget[15]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[15]["name"] = "f_all"
widget[15]["seq"] = "7"
widget[15]["type"] = "text"
widget[15] = ""
widget[16] = {}
widget[16]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[16]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[16]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[16]["grp"] = "widget"
widget[16]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[16]["name"] = "timezone"
widget[16]["seq"] = "7"
widget[16]["type"] = "text"
widget[16] = "EST5EDT"
widget[17] = {}
widget[17]["c_id"] = "17"
widget[17]["classname"] = "widget"
widget[17]["widget_id"] = "246"
widget[17]["grp"] = "grp2"
widget[17]["label"] = "5 - Widget XXX"
widget[17]["name"] = "fb_enable"
widget[17]["seq"] = "7"
widget[17]["type"] = "boolean"
widget[17] = "false"
```

etc ...

**EDIT 2**

This data is coming from a postgresql database, which I have no control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work using Lua tables, you will need to transform your data into a [hierarchical data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model).

For example

```
widgets =
{[246] = {[17] = {... meec = "CC5C9788"; extension = "1111"; hleenable = true};
          [11] = {... }
          ...}
...}
```

Then you can look up

```
widgets[246][17].meec
```

etc.

Whether this will work for you depends on the semantics of the widget data, which is not apparent from your question.

If you want to run generic queries, I suggest you use a database such as SQLite. There are a few Lua modules that support SQLite, including [lsqlite3](http://lua.sqlite.org), which is also available as a Lua rock. SQLite will import a well formed csv file.

After question EDIT 1...

If all the `widget["value"][xx]["name"]` field values are unique, you could do one pass over the data:

```
widget.index = {}
for i,t in pairs(widget.value) do widget.index[t.name] = i end
```

Then you can look up fields using, e.g,

```
widget.value[widget.index.meec].value
```

Comment: Doug, I'll be updating my example with the actual lua table layout instead of the logical layout you see above...

Comment: Doug, please see edit 1.  that shows what the actual lua table looks like.  In the interim, I'll try to read up on that wiki article you've included.  Unfortunately, changing database from postgresql to sqlite is not possible.

Comment: @dot, I've added a solution based on your example table. Can't you query the Postgres database directly?

Comment: Doug, your example has given me some ideas on how to make this work. Thanks!